# Skype auto logging in after reinstall?

Tags: windows, skype

I want to give a computer to a friend.
I removed Skype using the control panel (remove programs).

When he downloads Skype, it automatically goes to my account.

Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the configuration file for Skype from your computer.

Remove Skype completely with [**Revo Uninstaller**](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).  After uninstalling, it will scan for and remove all traces of Skype from your system.